# FileNetP8 File/move document from Object Store to Case folder

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet

I'm trying to dynamically move a document that is in my CMTOS Object Store in my Content Engine To a Case folder in a solution in IBM Advance Case Manager.
The document is transfered trough a web service from a distant server to the CMTOS Object Store.
I heard about subscription ... I mean, creating a Document class, creating a subscription (in the Content Engine Manager), and then open IBM Process Designer through the Workplace XT and add attachment in my workflow properties, but it doesn't seems to work. 
It's been a few days that i started to search on google, redbooks, ECM PLace and IBM developerWorks, but i havn't found any procedure to do that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[filenet events and subscriptions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v4r5m1/nav/5_6_2_1_16)

The above link contains the events and subscription how to , you have to create subscription for creation event on the class you have to file into the case folder . Then CE will take care of everything else no need for process designer and work flows

Comment: ok, but how can I retrieve a specific folder in my solution (no in the CE) to file my document in it ?

Comment: Problem solved ... I was searching in the wrong path in the CMTOS, I didn't know that the Case Folders where there :
/IBM Case Manager
  /Solution Deployments
    /<solution name 1>
      /Case Types
        /<Case Type 1a folder>
          /Cases
            /yyyy
              /mm
                /dd
                  /hh
                    /<case folder. Name = sequence number>

Answer (score 0):

This is an information on case manager subscription. When you deploy a case manager solution using case manager. It automatically creates subscriptions in case manager object stores which in turns takes care of filing the case documents to case folder. No need to create additional subscription for case documents filing.